# How to paginate searched results?

Tags: postgresql, graphql, typeorm, apollo-server, typegraphql

How to paginate searched results using cursor based?

this is my function for querying data and there is something wrong because when I load more data, there are items that are not related to the searched query?

```
    @UseMiddleware(isAuthenticated)
    @Query(() => PaginatedQuizzes)
    async quizzes(
        @Arg('limit', () => Int) limit: number,
        @Arg('cursor', () => String, { nullable: true }) cursor: string | null,
        @Arg('query', () => String, { nullable: true }) query: string | null
    ): Promise<PaginatedQuizzes> {
        const realLimit = Math.min(50, limit);
        const realLimitPlusOne = realLimit + 1;

        const qs = await getConnection()
            .getRepository(Quiz)
            .createQueryBuilder('q')
            .leftJoinAndSelect('q.author', 'author')
            .leftJoinAndSelect('q.questions', 'questions')

        if (query) {
            const formattedQuery = query.trim().replace(/ /g, ' <-> ');

            qs.where(
                `to_tsvector('simple',q.title) @@ to_tsquery('simple', :query)`,
                {
                    query: `${formattedQuery}:*`,
                }
            ).orWhere(
                `to_tsvector('simple',q.description) @@ to_tsquery('simple', :query)`,
                {
                    query: `${formattedQuery}:*`,
                }
            );
        }

        if (cursor) {
            qs.where('q."created_at" < :cursor', {
                cursor: new Date(parseInt(cursor)),
            });
        }

        const quizzes = await qs
            .orderBy('q.created_at', 'DESC')
            .take(realLimitPlusOne)
            .getMany();

        return {
            quizzes: (quizzes as [Quiz]).slice(0, realLimit),
            hasMore: (quizzes as [Quiz]).length === realLimitPlusOne,
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you so much for the responses, but i was able to solved it on my own using find option,

```
    @UseMiddleware(isAuthenticated)
    @Query(() => PaginatedQuizzes)
    async quizzes(
        @Arg('limit', () => Int) limit: number,
        @Arg('cursor', () => String, { nullable: true }) cursor: string | null,
        @Arg('query', () => String, { nullable: true }) query: string | null
    ): Promise<PaginatedQuizzes> {
        const realLimit = Math.min(20, limit);
        const realLimitPlusOne = realLimit + 1;

        let findOptionInitial: FindManyOptions = {
            relations: [
                'author',
                'questions',
            ],
            order: {
                created_at: 'DESC',
            },
            take: realLimitPlusOne,
        };

        let findOption: FindManyOptions;

        if (cursor && query) {
            const formattedQuery = query.trim().replace(/ /g, ' <-> ');

            findOption = {
                ...findOptionInitial,
                where: [
                    {
                        description: Raw(
                            (description) =>
                                `to_tsvector('simple', ${description}) @@ to_tsquery('simple', :query)`,
                            {
                                query: formattedQuery,
                            }
                        ),
                        created_at: LessThan(new Date(parseInt(cursor))),
                    },
                    {
                        title: Raw(
                            (title) =>
                                `to_tsvector('simple', ${title}) @@ to_tsquery('simple', :query)`,
                            {
                                query: formattedQuery,
                            }
                        ),
                        created_at: LessThan(new Date(parseInt(cursor))),
                    },
                ],
            };
        } else if (cursor) {
            findOption = {
                ...findOptionInitial,
                where: {
                    created_at: LessThan(new Date(parseInt(cursor))),
                },
            };
        } else if (query) {
            const formattedQuery = query.trim().replace(/ /g, ' <-> ');

            findOption = {
                ...findOptionInitial,
                where: [
                    {
                        description: Raw(
                            (description) =>
                                `to_tsvector('simple', ${description}) @@ to_tsquery('simple', :query)`,
                            {
                                query: formattedQuery,
                            }
                        ),
                    },
                    {
                        title: Raw(
                            (title) =>
                                `to_tsvector('simple', ${title}) @@ to_tsquery('simple', :query)`,
                            {
                                query: formattedQuery,
                            }
                        ),
                    },
                ],
            };
        } else {
            findOption = findOptionInitial;
        }

        const quizzes = await Quiz.find(findOption as FindManyOptions);

        return {
            quizzes: (quizzes as [Quiz]).slice(0, realLimit),
            hasMore: (quizzes as [Quiz]).length === realLimitPlusOne,
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom system instead of installing a heavy package which can have vulnerabilities.

Here is an example `controller` with `limit` and `page` parameters to get `n` elements on `x` page

```js
@Get('elements/:limit/:page')
  getElementsWithPagination(
    @Param('limit') limit: number,
    @Param('page') page: number,
  ): Promise<ElementsEntity[]> {
    return this.elementsService.getElementsWithPagination(limit, page);
  }
```

Here is the `service` to access to your repository

```js
async getElementsWithPagination(
    limit: number,
    page: number,
  ): Promise<ElementsEntity[]> {
    return this.elementsRepository.findElementsWithPagination(limit, page);
  }
```

And finally here is the `repository` with query arguments, ordered from newest to oldest

```js
async findElementsWithPagination(limit, page): Promise<ElementsEntity[]> {
    return this.find({
      take: limit,
      skip: limit * (page - 1),
      order: { createdAt: 'DESC' },
    });
  }
```

Thanks to this system, you can query `n` elements pages by pages.

Comment: What about large result sets? Doesn't take and skip load the whole result set into memory before throwing away the number of rows specified by skip? What if you have result sets with multiple 10k rows?

Answer (score 0):

Hey I've been using this cool package to paginate through a table check it out [here](https://github.com/benjamin658/typeorm-cursor-pagination)

```
import { buildPaginator } from 'typeorm-cursor-pagination';

const paginator = buildPaginator({
  entity: User,
  paginationKeys: ['id'],
  query: {
    limit: 10,
    order: 'ASC',
  },
});
const { data, cursor } = await paginator.paginate(queryBuilder);
```